Android Plural String resources with HTML Tag in Jetpack compose
I have a plurals in strings.xml which contains tag. I would need to show it with styled way
 <plurals name= "showing_results">
        <item quantity="one">Showing <b>%d result</b></item>
        <item quantity="other">Showing <b>%d results</b></item>
    </plurals>


I need to get a result Showing 4 results in Jetpack compose
